# What is the meaning of "Grab a hold of me"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

What is the meaning of:

> Grab a hold of me

And when to use it?

Comment: @ColleenV et al. What kind of "research" is the learner supposed to do when he doesn't know what the expression means? Isn't this the place to ask about such expressions?

Comment: @AlanCarmack See [Details Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/)  **Provide as much context as possible.** Tell us, where did you find this snippet? **Explain why you are confused.** Do you understand the individual meanings of the words? Why doesn't that help you understand the meaning? **Show your research.** Did you do anything to try to figure it out before you posted a question here? What was that and why didn't it help? [grab (a)hold of (someone)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grab+ahold+of+me) seems fairly well explained in The Free Dictionary. Why didn't that help?

Comment: @AshkanSirous Did you try to look up *a hold* without finding anything?  It's actually spelled *ahold*, so you should be able to find it in dictionaries if you look it up with that spelling: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ahold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Grab a hold of me

This literally means what it says, "Take hold of (some part) of my body," usually before doing something that might be dangerous.  You'll want to use it when you'd like someone to grab on to a part of your body (for safety) -- again, usually before doing something that might be dangerous.

As with most English expressions, it can be used satirically for humorous or derogatory effect, if desired:

> 'Grab a hold of me,' he said to her as they made their way into the crowded pub, 'and we'll see if we can fight a path to the alcohol.'